# How to write the following sql function in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

Is there any equal function to

`datepart(dw,getdate())` in SSRS expression which gives me the week number of a particular day

ie for monday it should be 2 .

Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 0):

The date in VB is zero-based, so just convert the DayOfWeek enum to its integer value and add one...

```
CInt(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek)+1
```